# Jinja2 Templating with Ansible, and zfill

Tags: python, ansible, jinja2

I use an ansible playbook:

Inventory:

```
[inventory]
ROUTER1 internet_bw=20
```

Playbook:

```
  vars:
    my_bandwidth: "{{ internet_bw }}"

  - name: IOS | Apply the NHRP QoS Configuration
    ios_config:
      provider: "{{ provider }}"
      authorize: yes
      parents: interface Tunnel0
      lines:
        - ip nhrp group INTERNET_GRP_{{ my_bandwitdth }}
```

When this is run it does this:

```
interface Tunnel0
 ip nhrp group INTERNET_GRP_20
```

I want it to show  as this:

```
interface Tunnel0
 ip nhrp group INTERNET_GRP_020
```

I have used a separate viable to achieve this called internet_bw_pad, but as my inventory contains 50 devices plus, I'd like to apply a function similar to zfill to pad out so I can maintain precision, and not have to set two variables.

I was hoping to find a jinja filter to achieve this but I cannot find one - does anyone have any ideas?

Thanks.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There's [format](http://jinja.pocoo.org/docs/2.9/templates/#format) filter: `{{ '%03d' | format(my_bandwitdth|int) }}`

Answer (score 0):

You can write your own filter:

```
 # -*- coding: utf-8 -*-
def zfill(value, width):
  """
  Zfill filter for ansible
  """
  return value.zfill(width)

class FilterModule(object):
  """Filter module"""

  def filters(self):
    return {
      'zfill': zfill
    }
```

Just put it into `./filter_plugins/zfill.py`, then you can use this in your playbook like that:

```
---

- name: Zfill play
  hosts: all
  tasks:
    - debug:
        msg: "{{'20'|zfill(3)}}"
```

In your case simply change `{{ my_bandwitdth }}` to `{{ my_bandwitdth|zfill(3) }}`